# How to apply arithmetic operators to query-replace-regex

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace

I am attempting to replace all "begin" and "dur" attribute values in my SVG code with one-tenth of (or ten times) their current values, in order to speed up/slow down animation for testing/debugging purposes.

e.g. replace dur="900s" with dur="90s"

My current regex: `\(dur\|begin\)="\([0-9.]+\)s?"`

and the replacement: `\1="\,(/ \2 10)s"`

I receive the error `Error evaluating replacement expression: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p #("900" 0 2 (rear-nonsticky display (fontified t face (nxml-attribute-value)) 2 3 (rear-nonsticky (display) fontified t face (nxml-attribute-value))))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\2` in your replacement is a string, and it needs to be a number in order to perform the division.

You could convert it to a number using `string-to-number`, but there's in-built shorthand for treating a capture group as a number; so you just need to change `\2` to `\#2`

Comment: just when you think you know all the dark corners of Emacs regexps.... :-)